# WARNING: 'aclocal-1.13' is missing on your system "Code::Blocks"

Tags: linux, codeblocks

During my installation of Code::Blocks on my kali-linux machine 
after executing ./configure command on my program directory , everything is okay until i try to make my program .
here is my error message :

```
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.13' is missing on your system. 
  You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or 'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'. 
  The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:  http://www.gnu.org/software/automake 
  It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run: 
     http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf     
     http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/ 
     http://www.perl.org/ 
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

i tried every single solution on the Internet
nothing worked , including autoreconf commands 
installing the automake tool , libtool which is already installed on my up-dated machine . also tried to install what the error message says which is m4 and perl but i found that they also are installed

if possible to provide me another way to install Code:blocks IDE , i'd be very happy , thanks .

Comment: your subject line says `aclocal-1.13` while your error msgs say `aclocal-1.15` Please edit your Q to clarify. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install automake.
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/aclocal /usr/bin/aclocal-1.13`
3. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/automake /usr/bin/automake-1.13`

Comment: I had a similar issue automake was already installed, creating the symlink solved the issue, but I also had to run "sudo automake --add-missing" after 3.

Comment: Fast solution and probably works but you are taking on that the version of automake and aclocal are the 1.13...

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `automake`

`sudo apt-get install automake` 
It includes the library you're looking for.

I had same problem compiling `PCRE` and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change anything such as the m4 files? That might be the problem, you changed something so that the compiler can't read it.

Comment: no i didn't i just uncompressed the source file with tar -xf , nothing more

Comment: @HussamY.Elshehawy  By the way, what version of Code::Blocks do you have? You may want to get a later version

Comment: problem solved @PowerPip , using the binary version and executing the following command , "dpgk -i *.deb " in the program directory , thanks .